# How to create a SQLite database from a registration form?

Tags: java, android

I must create a SQLite database called *Academia*, which will contain the *Student* table, and the following columns: ID, first name, last name, year of enrollment and number of points (between 1 and 100).

The new data for the table must be entered through a registration form, which contains text fields for entering new values in each column and three buttons: Entry, Present students and Delete student.

The *Entry student* button is used to enter a student in the table. By clicking on the *Present students* button, the app must must display the data of the first five students who have the number of points greater than 80. When clicking on the *Delete student* button, the Learner table (or its content) must be deleted from the *Academia* database.

The problem is that I got this error when pressing the *Entry student* button: **Error inserting Name= Number of points = Surname= Year of enrollment =
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near " points ": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Cursant(Name, Number of points, Surname, Year of enrollment) VALUES (?,?,?,?)**

And the *FATAL EXCEPTION* (?): **main
Process: com.example.academia, PID: 25052                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.example.academia/databases/AcademiaDatabase                                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:58)**

What am I doing wrong?

Below the code for the app:

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.academia;
import static com.example.academia.AcademiaDbHelper.TABLE_NAME;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name, surname, yearOfEnrollment, numberOfPoints;
    Button entryStudent, presentStudent, deleteStudent;
    private AcademiaDbHelper AcademiaDbHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        name = findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        surname = findViewById(R.id.editTextSurname);
        yearOfEnrollment = findViewById(R.id.editTextYearOfEnrollment);
        numberOfPoints = findViewById(R.id.editTextNumberOfPoints);
        entryStudent = findViewById(R.id.entry_Student_btn);
        presentStudent = findViewById(R.id.present_Student _btn);
        deleteStudent = findViewById(R.id.delete_Student_btn);
        AcademiaDbHelper = new AcademiaDbHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = AcademiaDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        entryStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nameValue = name.getText().toString();
                String surnameValue = surname.getText().toString();
                String yearValue = yearOfEnrollment.getText().toString();
                String pointsValue = numberOfPoints.getText().toString();
                AcademiaDbHelper.addStudent(nameValue, surnameValue, yearValue, pointsValue);
            }
        });
        deleteStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_NAME);
            }
        });
        present.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"title", "content"}, null, null, null, null, null);
                if (pointsValue > 80) {
                    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String surname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME));
                        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.COLUMN_NAME_NAME));
                        String yearOfEnrollment = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.COLUMN_NAME_ YEAR_OF_ENROLLMENT));
                        String numberOfPoints = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Student.COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER_OF_POINTS));
                    }
                    cursor.close();
                    db.close();
                }
            });
        });
    }}
```

**AcademiaDbHelper**

```
package com.example.academia;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
public class AcademiaDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "AcademiaDatabase";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Student";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME = "Surname";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NAME = "Name";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_YEAR_OF_ENROLLMENT = "Year of enrollment";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER_OF_POINTS= "Number of points";
    public AcademiaDbHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_YEAR_OF_ENROLLMENT + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER_OF_POINTS+ " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    public void addStudent(String surnameValue, String nameValue, String yearValue, String pointsValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_SURNAME, surnameValue);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NAME, nameValue);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_YEAR_OF_ENROLLMENT, yearValue);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME_NUMBER_OF_POINTS, pointsValue);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

**activity_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextName"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="78dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/surname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="29dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:text="Surname"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextSurname"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="132dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year_of_enrollment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="239dp"
        android:text="Year of enrollment"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextYearOfEnrollment"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="185dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="59dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSurname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="162dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/surname"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="116dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextYearOfEnrollment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="234dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="37dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="date"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/year_of_enrollment"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="177dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumberOfPoints"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/number_of_points"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="249dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_of_points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="308dp"
        android:text="Number of points"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/editTextNumberOfPoints"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="267dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/entry_Student_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="473dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="100dp"
        android:text="Entry Student"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/present_Student_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextNumberOfPoints"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.499" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/present_Student _btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="291dp"
        android:text="Present"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/delete_Student_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/entry_Student_btn" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete_Student_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="119dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="139dp"
        android:text="Delete student"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/present_Student_btn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```